# Make element appear html5/css3

Tags: css, html

On my homepage I have everything fade in at once when the home page is accessed, I'd like my logo to a be drawn in from the bottom up instead of fading in.

I was thinking of using something like this:

```
.wrapper {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100px;
height: 100px; 
border: 1px solid black;

position: absolute;
left: -100px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: blue;
transition: 1s;
transition: 1s;
left: 0;
```

}

But instead have a gray box covering the logo when the page is accessed, pulling up and staying hidden(or like 1 px wide), so the logo stays visible, what do I need to change? Also taken the }'s etc out so it would show properly I haven't forgotten :)

Edit:
Just to clarify, I want my logo hidden with a gray box then on access I want it unveiled and kept visible

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the HTML/CSS of the logo, a jsFiddle would be ideal

Comment: @Aziz Hi, this is the link to a jsfiddle, Everything's offline at the moment so only the navigation bar shows!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2mxdsvtq/

Comment: OK. what do you mean by "drawn up"? Have a look at https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ and tell me which effect you are trying to acheive

Comment: @Aziz Similar to the slide in up animation :)

Comment: Do you want it to have a jQuery-like slideUp animation or to fly into the viewport from the bottom of the screen?

Comment: And when should this occur, on click, on page load, on document ready, on scroll?